# My R^2 for the validation data is above 1, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am doing cross validation for my regressor, I've split my dataset into training, validation, and testing. I am running the CV on my validation datapoints but the R^2 I am getting is very high and I think I am doing something wrong. Any clue? THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
names = data_set.columns
d = scaler.fit_transform(data_set)
scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=names)
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]
scaled_df.head(200)

x_train1, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(X_normalized, y_for_normalized, test_size=0.10)


training_data_points_1= pd.concat([x_train1,y_train1],axis=1)
training_data_points_1


y_train = y_train1[:-15] 
y_train


x_train = x_train1[:-15]
x_train



x_validation=x_and_y_for_validation.drop(["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"], axis=1)


y_validation=x_and_y_for_validation.drop(["Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"],axis=1)
y_validation



lin_regressor = LinearRegression()

# pass the order of your polynomial here  
poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)

# convert to be used further to linear regression
X_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_train)

# fit this to Linear Regressor
linear_regg=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train) 



linear_regg.coef_



from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

crossvalidation_poly = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True) 



for i in range(1,11):
    poly_cross_validation = PolynomialFeatures(degree=i)
    X_current = poly.fit_transform(x_validation)
    model = lin_regressor.fit(X_current, y_validation)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X_current,y_validation, scoring='r2', cv=crossvalidation_poly,
 n_jobs=1)
    

    print("\n\nDegree-"+str(i) +" polynomial: R^2 for every fold: " + str(np.abs(scores)))
          
          #+" training: " + str(np.abs(train_index))+" \ntesting: " + str(np.abs(test_index)))

    print('\033[1m'+"Degree-"+str(i)+ '\033[1m'+ " polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(scores))) + '\033[0m'+ ", STD: " + str(np.std(scores)))
```

Degree-1 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.0927268  0.10108679 9.72278481]
Degree-1 polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 3.3055327986619965, STD: 4.586017809565009

Degree-2 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.45544226 0.63336232 3.36329753]
Degree-2 polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 1.4840340355778388, STD: 1.60626603495359

Degree-3 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.00127055 1.01431673 0.49328318]
Degree-3 polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.5029568219562919, STD: 0.627725299222276

Degree-4 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [6.53315081 0.80015745 4.63525957]
Degree-4 polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 3.9895226091718476, STD: 2.3846083385101253

Comment: pretty sure that R^2 can't be greater than 1 -> something wrong in the way that you are calculating it

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thank you. Would you please elaborate more? What's wrong with the way I am calculating it?

Comment: probably worth checking what's inside `scores`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the scoring inside "scores" is r2, are you implying something that I can't get?

Comment: no, I'm not one of those that hints what's the solution, it was just a suggestion... can you please what  `print(scores)` outputs?

Comment: also, you are overriding `scores =` at each iteration of the for loop, your are not appending values

Comment: `print (scores)`[-1.80800158 -0.65058376 -3.72859467]

Comment: ok, my bad, it's because the R2 is bounded for a poly model on training set, not on validation set... if the val set is very different from train set, then it can be very negative... thus, a -3 r2 is very very bad, it means that it explains that data worst than just taking the avg

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thank you. So my code is correct? the thing is the validation set is taken from the training set randomly before training the model with the training set. I don't understand why the R^2 is very bad.

Comment: Maybe you have more feature than samples, maybe the data is very uncorrelated, I can't tell you... however, a negative R2 is very bad, and any 2 model with negative R2 are as bad one to another, independently which actual r2 score they have